# Where to offer mhchem support?

Tags: discussion, mhchem

I am about to finalize the MathJax/mhchem 3.0.0 (which is quite a large update). To my knowledge, the largest user group can be found here. Would you mind if I put a link in the documentation to meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com and say that support for the mhchem syntax will be offered here? I will subscribe to the mhchem tag, of course.

Comment: I think it is great having the developer on board here. I personally think that we would profit from user input. However, please bear in mind, that you need to gain reputation in order to ask questions on Meta first, so it might not be as barrier less as you think. I personally have no objection of using the site this way.

Comment: Oh, I see. I particularly like the "no registration required" setting of chemistry.SE and I assumed it would be the same on meta. But then, with most users being here anyway that might be acceptable.

Comment: Users need five reputation to participate on meta, but really I don't think there will be many (any?) users with less than five rep that have some feedback to give. Rep is pretty easy to get anyway. (Note that [meta.se] doesn't have the five reputation requirement, but it's for all Stack Exchange sites)

Comment: I wasn't worrying about SE users, but about non-SE users. First, they need to register, then they will get a message about missing reputation. This will be frustrating. (While on chemistry, you need neither an account nor reputation.)

Comment: It is now here in the documentation: https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/

Comment: @mhchem It might be a good idea if you add your previous comment as an answer to directly send anyone to the official support page. In any case, thank you for sharing your efforts with us and we are happy to have such a dedicated developer among us.

Comment: mhchem v3 is live, congrats @mhchem

Comment: @mosa Woohoo!!!

Comment: mhchem, does [this MathJax v2.7.1 release](https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/#upcoming-bug-fix-release-mathjax-v271) mean that all (or most) of the fanciest new mhchem stuff will be available wherever the most-recent MathJax version is loaded?

Comment: There is no difference between MathJax v2.7.0 and v2.7.1 in this respect. If you request `"mhchem.js"`, you will get the old "core" version. When you add the parameter [`legacy: false`](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=legacy#tex-and-latex-extensions), it will load the new version. Difference: v2.7.0 linked to the newest version on CDN, v2.7.1 has a snapshot of a very recent version included. To get the most up-to-date version, request `"[mhchem]/mhchem.js"` and set `[mhchem]` to a [proper path](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/).

Comment: There is no difference between MathJax v2.7.0 and v2.7.1 in this respect. If you request `"mhchem.js"`, you will get the old "core" version. When you add the parameter [`legacy: false`](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html?highlight=legacy#tex-and-latex-extensions), it will load the new version. Difference: v2.7.0 linked to the newest version on CDN, v2.7.1 has a snapshot of a very recent version included. To get the most up-to-date version, request `"[mhchem]/mhchem.js"` and set `[mhchem]` to a [proper path](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The official documentation of MathJax/mhchem 3.0.0 can be found at https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/. It includes a test drive for live testing.

Please be aware that you might not be using the latest version. (Even StackExchange does not run the latest version, released just a couple of days ago.)

If you cannot find a solution there or with a web search, you might post your question here, at https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/ with the `mhchem` tag.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, Chemistry.stackexchange.com is probably one of the largest (if not the single largest by a significant margin) sites to use MathJax with `mhchem`. As such, it makes sense to offer documentation help here.

The caveat applies that you need five reputation points to ask/answer on meta. For most users of Stack Exchange, that is no problem, and most of the first-time posters on chemistry wouldn’t care anyway. Thus, the only people we cannot reach are those that use `mhchem`, are not on SE, and do not have any chemistry questions to ask/answer. I would expect that group to be significantly small, though.

So yes, feel free to ask `mhchem` support questions on here, they definitely benefit chem.SE users and may help keeping things in one place. But be prepared to open at least one other channel (e.g. e-mail) for people that do not use this site.